# Algoritmo para popular tabelas no PostgresSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, algoritmo

Estou escrevendo um algoritmo para popular todas as tabelas de um banco de dados em Postgres. Eu já consigo popular todas as tabelas **que não possuem relacionamento**, da seguinte maneira:

1. Obtenho todas as tabelas com a seguinte consulta:

   ```
   SELECT table_name
   FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND
   table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
   ```
2. Para a lista de tabelas obtidas, faço um laço, e para cada tabela obtenho suas propriedades (nome da coluna, tipo de dado, se aceita nulo ou não, máximo de caracteres):

   ```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE,
      IS_NULLABLE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NOME_DA_TABELA'
   ```
3. Com essa lista de propriedades monto dinamicamente o INSERT

   ```
   INSERT INTO NOME_TABELA(prop1, prop2, prop3) VALUES(value1, value2, value3)
   ```

   Cada valor é gerado aleatoriamente baseado no tipo da propriedade, exemplo:

   - Inteiro: 65422
   - Caractere: "Lorem ipsum..."
   - Data: 2016-12-12 20:00

E assim por diante para cada tipo de dado aceito pelo algoritmo. Se ele encontrar algum tipo de dado que não é aceito, a aplicação termina (o que é o esperado).

4. E por fim, com o INSERT montado executo a consulta no banco de dados

Os passos desse algoritmo funcionam perfeitamente para **tabelas onde não existem relacionamentos**.

---

Para tabelas que possuem relacionamento (1:N, 1:1, N:N), eu precisaria encontrar primeiramente todas as chaves estrangeiras e entender de quais tabelas elas vêem, para inserir os dados nessa tabela "Pai" guardar os IDs e depois inserir nas tabelas "Filhas" associando assim suas chaves estrangeiras. Porém como fazer isso de uma maneira simples?

É interessante notar que eu já consigo obter a lista de todas as chaves estrangeiras através da seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass AS table_from
      ,conname
      ,pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
WHERE  contype IN ('f', 'p ')
AND    n.nspname = 'public' -- your schema here
ORDER  BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```

Sou grato por sugestão.

**Obs: O algoritmo está sendo desenvolvido em Python.**

Answer (score 1):

Você já tem tudo o que precisa. Basta implementar uma função recursiva que insere uma linha na tabela da FK antes de inserir a linha da tabela atual. É basicamente fazer uma busca em uma árvore.

Segue um exemplo:

```
procedimento obter_fks(tabela)
  # Retorna um array com o nome das tabelas
  # Você disse que já tem sabe como obter essa informação
fim procedimento

procedimento inserir_linha(tabela)
  tabelas_ligadas = obter_fks(tabela)
  chaves_tabelas_ligadas = dicionário zerado

  para cada tabela_fk em tabelas_ligadas
    chave = inserir_linha(tabela_fk)
    chaves_tabelas_ligadas[tabela] = chave
  fim para

  # Você disse que sua rotina que já é funcional
  # Use a chaves_tabelas_ligadas para popular as FKs

  retornar a PK da linha inserida
fim procedimento
```